# Verify SSL certificate against various CRL files

Tags: bash, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, verify

I am given multiple certificate files e.g. "cert1.crt", "cert2.crt" etc, and multiple CRL lists, "list1.crl", "list2.crl" etc. No rootCA or any other type of files are provided. My task is to find out what certificates have NOT been revoked. Despite extensive search for "verification" command I failed to find any command or procedure that would provide me at least a clue. In the end, I managed to do some bash script aerobatics which let me manually test serial number for each .crt file

```
for((i=1;i<9;i++))
do
echo $i
fileIn="crl"$i".crl"
#serial is manually c/p from each .crt file
serial="1319447396"
OUTPUT="$(openssl crl -in $fileIn -noout -text | grep $serial)"
echo $OUTPUT
done
```

This way I could do it manually one at a time, but it will work only for small number of files (9 at present). With tens of files it would get tiresome and ineffective, with 100+ it would get impossible to do it like this.

I was wondering is there a "smart" way to validate .crt against .crl? Or at least is there a way to bash script the job so I wouldn't have to check each .crt manually? Right now it's way beyond my scripting knowledge.

So, in pseudo, I would be thrilled if something like this existed:

```
openssl x509 -verify cert1.cert -crl_list list8.crl
```

Comment: https://raymii.org/s/articles/OpenSSL_manually_verify_a_certificate_against_a_CRL.html

Comment: Thanks, Hugo. I am well aware of this article, as well as of some other articles since I tried to search as much as I could before asking a question, yet it didn't provide me with solution to my question since verification method is not applicable to the problem at hand. As I mentioned in my post, I am not provided a CA file which is used in  verification method given by the site you mentioned. I did find OpenSSL way to solve it, but what I lacked is bash command knowledge to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, yes, each certificate is checked against a CRL, as is [detailed in this guide](https://raymii.org/s/articles/OpenSSL_manually_verify_a_certificate_against_a_CRL.html).

But, Actually, each crl is a simple list of revoked certificate serial numbers.
The list contained in a crl could be expanded with:

```
openssl crl -inform DER -text -noout -in mycrl.crl
```

Asuming the crl is in DER form (adapt as needed).

1. Expand each (all) crl to a text file, like:

   ```
   openssl crl -inform DER -text -noout -in mycrl.crl > mycrl.crl.txt
   ```

   The out file could be reduced to only the `Serial Number:` lines.
2. Get the Serial Number from the text expansion of a cert:

   ```
   mycrt=$(openssl x509 -in mycrt.com.crt -serial -noout)
   mycrt=${mycrt#*=}
   ```
3. grep the serial number in all text files from step one (if one match the cert is revoked) in **one** call to grep:

   ```
   if grep -rl "$mycrt" *.crl.txt 2>/dev/null; then
       echo "the certificate has been revoked"
   fi
   ```

Full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create (if they don't exist) files for all the crl given.
for crl in *.crl; do
    if [[ ! -e "$crl.txt" ]]; then
    openssl crl -inform DER -text -noout -in "$crl" |
        awk -F ': ' '/Serial Number:/{print $2}'> "$crl.txt"
    fi
done

# Process all certificates
for crt in *.crt; do
    mycrt=$(openssl x509 -in "$crt" -serial -noout)
    mycrt=${mycrt#*=}
    if grep -rl "$mycrt" *.crl.txt; then
        echo "Certificate $crt has been revoked"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you. It works (btw. it tells that all of my certificates have been revoked). Honestly, you introduced so many new commands to me that I'm not even sure how this works. On my own it would probably take me days, or even more, of dedicated bash tutorial studying, time which, alas, I don't have at my disposal at the moment, so you really helped a lot. You did a great job explaining, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this in a way that's maybe not optimal, but requires much less bash knowledge. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for((j=1;j<10;j++))
do
indicator=0
cert="cert"$j".crt"
for((i=1;i<9;i++))
do
infile="crl"$i".crl"
SERIAL="$(openssl x509 -noout -text -in $cert | grep Serial | cut -d  'x' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1)"
OUTPUT="$(openssl  crl -inform DER -in $infile -noout -text | grep $SERIAL )"
if [ -n $OUTPUT ]
then ((indicator++))
fi
done
echo $cert
if [ $indicator == 0 ]
then echo "not revoked" 
else
echo "revoked"
fi
done
```

Comment: Please check the case of SERIAL (lowercase) vs the case in output (uppercase). You should make them equal. A `SERIAL=${SERIAL^^}` should be enough.

Comment: In this, you are executing commands for `m*n` (m=number of crl's, n=number of crt's). In my code, the crl's are all processed only once, then one grep command for each crt. For a low number of crt's that is not so important, but for many crt's and crl's that will make the script quite slow.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, sorontar! Your script is definitely much superior, yet with my present knowledge of bash I found it more convenient to do it my way i.e. less different commands. I am kinda running out of time, preparing for my Cryptography exam next week, so I have to find what works for me and carry on, studying different problems.  Thanks again, you were of great help and I really like your code!